# Long-lived multithreaded client for a proprietary protocol (Python, select, epoll)

Tags: python, asynchronous, client, asyncsocket

first thing is, I'm a long time lurker but the first time user, I'd like to thank you all for creating the site!

I'm in a situation that I need to implement the client part of a proprietary protocol. The protocol uses TCP/IP underneath and the message flow can be summarized as follows:

1. Client connects to server
2. Client expresses interest in data of a certain type
3. If server has any such data, it it sent down to the client
4. Client confirms the reception to the server
5. Client now needs to tell the server that it is still interested in data of the same type
6. Server sends the data to the client as it is coming in
7. Client needs to send application-level keep-alive requests to the server from time to time (like each minute or so)
8. Some messages from the server require the client to send a reply back to the server
9. Client disconnects

All of that is to happen within a single TCP session, which is to be a long-living one, sort of like WebSocket I imagine.

Another thing is that the client is to be deployed on a multi-threaded server and should allow for concurrent access from several threads, which means that a single thread should be able to 'subscribe' to messages of a certain type from the server and should also be able to send the messages to it.

I'm well aware of GIL hence I guess it doesn't much make to comment on that, I'm only writing a client, I can't change any other pieces of the architecture.

So the thing is that I've never had to delve below the HTTP level, I've been lucky enough to always use some already existing libraries and on the other hand, I haven't done that much network programming, that would be the first time I'll be something like that myself.

I'd like it to be an opportunity for me to learn more about all the asynchronous libraries/tools/toolkits like select, epoll, libev or gevent.

The trouble is that most of the resources on the web deal with writing servers and I'm not even sure if that I'm to deploy the client on a multi-threaded doesn't mean all of them won't do much. All of the servers people are obviously single-threaded but it's not clear if it's because multiple threads aren't needed or if it's because things like epoll don't really like multiple threads using them.

The server clearly treats all the clients like if they were single-threaded units so I think I will need to serialize the access to the client. The thing I can't quite get is how to make sure the server responses match threads and vice versa. If one thread receives a message but another thread needs to confirm a message it received prior to the former one's getting a chance of confirming it, then how I can be sure the messages simply don't get mixed up?

What do you think about it all? Are asynchronous libraries a good choice in this case? Can you think of any code samples I could have a look at? I'm using Python but the question I think is generic enough that I can use C, C++ or Java for inspiration.

Many, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for each thread (each client) to open their own socket? In that case, it's all a non-issue: Only the client in that one thread has a handle on that socket and so it automatically gets the correct data from the server. For the server, all of these connections from the client will look like completely independent client connections (which is exactly what they are).

If one of the requirements is to limit the overall number of network connections then you could construct a special thread that maintains the connection to the server, and which locally receives communication requests from the various threads/ But using the independent sockets (one per thread) is probably much simpler.

Do you absolutely have to use application level keepalive? Because TCP can do this for you, automatically. If the keepalive is not received in time then the socket is closed, thus informing the other side that the connection has timed out. Do consider this as an option, if it's possible in your case.

Finally, if you don't have to do the application-level keepalive you can take advantage of one of the nice aspects of multi-threaded programming: Develop each thread as if it's the only one out there and you then don't need to worry about anything asynchronous at all. For example, you can write your client to send request and then blocking-wait for resonse, do computation and either send result or check if more data from the server has arrived. The data from the server will have accumulated in the TCP receive window on your side. This also serves as a means of flow control: If your client becomes too slow and the receive window is full then the server cannot send anymore. This might block the server, so you need to see whether the server can handle this situation.